# Are there limitations to what is possible on a subdomain rather than a domain or risks allowing strangers to use them?

Tags: dns

I'm thinking about creating a little service for free subdomains with full DNS control. So in this situation I buy example.com and I allow people to register a subdomain through a form. After registration they get full control over that subdomain. Are there any limitations or risks to consider when giving strangers this power?

My intention is for it to be used for developers and sysadmins to use it in all kinds of ways, from making sites, use it to show work in progress to the world, test MX records, testing of automatically getting ssl certs using certbot etc.

Comment: At least one common wisdom is to register one domain to do only that (that is devoted only to your "users") so that it is not the same domain that you use for your own organization. This allows at least to isolate problems. Leaving subdomain free to take by anyone does have consequences indeed. Among others, you should register the base domain on the Public Suffix List to avoid cookies problem.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Sounds like good advice, some thing I was thinking about solving by adding a warning at first, but your solution sounds better